# Recommended way to watch events with MetaMask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, events

I always get in trouble with things like `var filter = web3.eth.filter({fromBlock: '5139365', toBlock: 'latest'}); filter.watch(function(_err, _resp){ ...` when using MetaMask as provider.

What is the recommended way to watch for new blocks when using the MetaMask provider?

Comment: What is the probles do you have with that approach?

Comment: It simply does not work. No error and no or just one callback

Comment: I've used the FilterProvider from MetaMask Provider Engine https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine with infura.io that doesn't support filters.

Comment: Is it because the provider that's associated with MetaMask is not using web sockets?